# En Java, ¿cómo puedo enviar información entre clases?

Tags: java, android-studio, objeto, app, class

Tengo tres clases que deben comunicarse entre sí y estoy teniendo problemas para enviar información entre ellas. La clase A accede a un método de la clase B y esta escribe el resultado en la clase C. Ahora A debe leer el resultado de la clase C.

El problema está en que B instancia un objeto para escribir el resultado en C y luego A instancia otro objeto completamente distinto para leer ese resultado de C. **Al ser objetos distintos A no puede leer lo que B escribió en C**.

En resumen, si B dice que coche=rojo, cuando A va a leer de C el color del coche, C le devuelve "null".

¿Alguien sabría cómo resolverlo?

Pongo aquí un ejemplo:

**Clase principal:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Database db = new Database();
    Utils u = new Utils();

    db.miMetodo();

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText("El texto escrito por 'Database' es: \t"+u.getTexto());
}
```

**Clase de intermediación**

```
public class Utils {
String texto;

public String getTexto() {
    return texto;
}

public void setTexto(String texto) {
    this.texto = texto;
}
```

**Clase que escribe para que la principal lo reciba:**

```
public class Database {

Utils u = new Utils();

public void miMetodo(){
    u.setTexto("Hola");
}
```

[image: Resultado obtenido al ejecutar]

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código y cuál es el error concretamente? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta. Pon código y error como texto, no capturas de imagen.

Comment: Creas dos objetos de `Utils` diferentes. En programación orientada a objetos, cada vez que usas `new` estás literalmente creando un objeto nuevo, con todo lo que tiene *dentro*. Así que creas uno, le guardas el texto "Hola", y luego creas otro objeto nuevo e intentas leerlo... obviamente ahí no hay nada. Imagínate que tienes dos cajas, metes tu cartera en una, vas a la otra caja e intentas sacar tu cartera... estará ahí?? Pues no, porque la guardaste en otra caja diferente! Es exactamente lo mismo con objetos, necesitas *pasar* el objeto entre clases para poder *compartirlo*

Comment: Dices que tienes problemas para comunicarlas entre ellas, pero realmente **nunca las has comunicado**, son clases totalmente separadas. Intenta modificar el constructor de `Database` para que reciba un objeto `Utils`, pásale el objeto utils que creas en la activity y entonces si podrás tener las clases comunicadas!

Comment: Muchas gracias Benito-B, duda resuelta!! ^^'